# Shape not rendering on HTML 5 canvas when using non-hardcoded parameters

Tags: html, typescript, html5-canvas

I'm trying to create a basic HTML 5 game using typescript but I have run into trouble with rendering a circle of a size that is non hard-coded.

My code so far:

**Circle.ts**

```
import { IDrawable } from './../Interfaces/IDrawable';
import {BaseShape} from "./BaseShape";
export class Circle extends BaseShape implements IDrawable{

private _radius : number;

public get radius(){
    return this._radius;
}

public set radius(val : number){
    this._radius = val;
}

constructor(context : CanvasRenderingContext2D,radius : number, x : number, y : number, color : string = "red", lineWidth : number = 2) {
    super(context , x, y, color, lineWidth);

}

public  draw = () : void => {

    this.context.save();
    this.context.beginPath();
    this.context.strokeStyle = this.color;
    this.context.lineWidth = this.lineWidth;
    this.context.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    this.context.stroke();       
    this.context.restore();

}
```

}

**Game.ts**

```
import { Circle } from './Shapes/Circle';


export default class Game{
    private circle : Circle;

    constructor(private ctx : CanvasRenderingContext2D ){
        this.circle = new Circle(ctx, 200, 300, 50, "blue", 5);
    }

    public Start() : void{
        requestAnimationFrame(() => this.Start());

        this.ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        this.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 1280, 720);
        this.circle.draw();
}
```

}

The background renders fine but the circle won't render at all unless I change the line:

```
this.context.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
```

and hard-code the parameters.

Not sure what the problem is, tried both using an arrow function for `draw()` and using a normal method, also tried supplying the context as a method parameter for `draw()` with the same result.

Comment: This usually means the arguments are the wrong type (usually String instead of number), but I'm guessing Typescript should catch that?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are passing wrong argument to constructor of Circle. Se parameters of constructor and values you pass.

```
context: CanvasRenderingContext2D    ctx
radius: number                       200
x: number                            300
y: number                            50 
color: string                       "blue"
lineWidth: number                    5
```

I think you have switched the order of radius and coordinates parameter.